# Sequelize error exception doesn't indicate which line is wrong

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Here is my source code for testing. I put one attribute incorrect on purpose in the where clause. I want to know which line went wrong from error stack. Normally, nodeJS should show which line is wrong at the top of error stack with file path and line number. But with Sequelize library, it doesn't show such info. I'm expecting a statement like "error from /[project folder path]/index.js line 40" on the top of error stack.

Source code:

```
"use strict";

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('testdb', 'xxx', 'xxx', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
});

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    birthday: Sequelize.DATE
});

const insert = async () => {
    return sequelize.sync()
        .then(() => User.create({
            username: 'janedoe',
            birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20)
        }))
        .then(jane => {
            console.log(jane.toJSON());
        });
}

const query = async () => {
    return User.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'username', 'birthday'],
        where: {
            usernamexxxx: 'janedoe',
            birthday: '1981-07-21 07:00:00+00'
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
        throw err;
    });
};

const close = async () => {
    return sequelize.connectionManager.close().then(() => console.log('shut down gracefully'));
}

async function test() {
    try {
        await insert();
        console.log('insert done');

        const result = await query();
        console.log(result[0].dataValues);
        console.log('query done');


    }
     catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    }
    finally{
        await close();
        console.log('connection closed');
    }
}

test();
```

Error stack:

```
jfan@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/temp/sequelize$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
$ node index.js
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" ("id"   SERIAL , "username" VARCHAR(255), "birthday" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'users' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "users" ("id","username","birthday","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING *;
{
  id: 18,
  username: 'janedoe',
  birthday: 1980-07-20T07:00:00.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-06-10T19:19:59.765Z,
  createdAt: 2020-06-10T19:19:59.765Z
}
insert done
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "username", "birthday" FROM "users" AS "user" WHERE "user"."usernamexxxx" = 'janedoe' AND "user"."birthday" = '1981-07-21 07:00:00.000 +00:00';
SequelizeDatabaseError: column user.usernamexxxx does not exist
    at Query.formatError (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:366:16)
    at /home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:72:18
    at tryCatcher (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
shut down gracefully
connection closed
Done in 0.44s.
jfan@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/temp/sequelize$
```

Here is what I am expecting:
I want to see something like below, something indicates the exact file and exact position where exception happened.

```
jfan@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/temp$ cat index2.js 
function test() {
    throw Error('test error');
}

test();
jfan@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/temp$ 
jfan@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/temp$ 
jfan@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/temp$ node index2.js 
/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/index2.js:2
    throw Error('test error');
    ^

Error: test error
    at test (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/index2.js:2:11)   <--- Exact place where error is
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jfan/Desktop/temp/index2.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
jfan@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/temp$
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this github issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8199#issuecomment-324947145

```js
const Sequelize= require('sequelize');

Sequelize.Promise.config({
  longStackTraces: true
});
```

Comment: cant use that anymore for Sequelize 6 + because for these version it didnt use Bluebird as its promise anymore